# Java aggregate same objects into one

Tags: java, collections, java-stream, streams-api

I'm quite new into programming and got a tricky question.
I got an object which has multiple parameters:

```
public class SampleObject {
    private String number;
    private String valueOne;
    private String valueTwo;
    private String valueThree;
    
    // getters, setters, all-args constructor
}
```

Every object always has non-null `number` attribute as well as one of three values-field. So for example, if `valueOne` is not `null`, the other two value fields `valueTwo` and `valueThree` would be `null`.

So here's my problem:

The `SampleObject` is referenced in `AnotherClass` which looks so:

```
public class AnotherClass {
    private UUID id;
    private List<SampleObject> sampleObjects;
    
    // getters, setters, all-args constructor
}
```

I am receiving one object of `AnotherClass` containing multiple entities of `SampleClass` in a list.

What I want to do is merge all `SampleObject`s which got the same number into one object and provide a map, where the number is the key and value are the value parameters. For example:

```
Sample1(number:"1", valueOne="1", valueTwo=null, valueThree=null)
Sample2(number:"1", valueOne=null, valueTwo="2", valueThree=null)
Sample3(number:"1", valueOne=null, valueTwo=null, valueThree="3")
Sample4(number:"2", valueOne="5", valueTwo=null, valueThree=null)
```

Desired state:

```
Sample1Merged(number:"1", valueOne="1", valueTwo="2", valueThree="3")
Sample4(number:"2", valueOne="5", valueTwo=null, valueThree=null)
```

What I have already done is the following:

```
final Map<String, SampleObject> mapOfMergedSamples = new LinkedHashMap<>();

anotherClass.getSampleObjects().stream()
    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(SampleObject::getNumber))
    .forEach(s -> mapOfMergedSamples.put(s.getNumber(), new SampleObject(Stream.of(s.getValueOne(), s.getValueTwo())
        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
        .collect(Collectors.joining()), s.getValueThree()))
    );
    
return mapOfMergedSamples;
```

The problem with my current try is that every number gets overwritten because they have the same key in the map (the number in the `SampleObject`) does someone know how can I archive my desired state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your usage of `Collector.joining()` I assume that you want to concatenate all non-null values without any delimiters (anyway it can be easily changed).

In order to combine `SampleObject` instances having the same `number` property, you can group them into an intermediate `Map` where the `number` would serve as Key and a custom accumulation type (having properties `valueOne`, `valueTwo`, `valueThree`) would be a Value (note: if you don't want to define a new type, you can put the accumulation right into the `SampleObject`, but I'll go with a separate class because this approach is more flexible).

Here's it might look like (for convenience, I've implemented `Consumer` interface):

```
public class SampleObjectAccumulator implements Consumer<SampleObject> {
    private StringBuilder valueOne = new StringBuilder();
    private StringBuilder valueTwo = new StringBuilder();
    private StringBuilder valueThree = new StringBuilder();

    @Override
    public void accept(SampleObject sampleObject) {
        if (sampleObject.getValueOne() != null) valueOne.append(sampleObject.getValueOne());
        if (sampleObject.getValueTwo() != null) valueTwo.append(sampleObject.getValueTwo());
        if (sampleObject.getValueThree() != null) valueThree.append(sampleObject.getValueThree());
    }
    
    public SampleObjectAccumulator merge(SampleObjectAccumulator other) {
        valueOne.append(other.valueOne);
        valueTwo.append(other.valueTwo);
        valueThree.append(other.valueThree);
        return this;
    }
    
    public SampleObject toSampleObject(String number) {
        return new SampleObject(
            number,
            valueOne.toString(),
            valueTwo.toString(),
            valueThree.toString()
        );
    }
    
    // getters
}
```

To create an intermediate Map we can use Collector [`groupingBy()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy(java.util.function.Function,java.util.stream.Collector)) and as its downstream Collector, in order to leverage the custom accumulation type, we can provide a custom collector, which can instantiated using factory method [`Collector.of()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collector.html#of(java.util.function.Supplier,java.util.function.BiConsumer,java.util.function.BinaryOperator,java.util.stream.Collector.Characteristics...)).

Then we need to create a stream over the entries of the intermediate map in order to transform the Value.

Note that sorting applied in only the second stream.

```
AnotherClass anotherClass = // initializing the AnotherClass instance

final Map<String, SampleObject> mapOfMergedSamples = anotherClass.getSampleObjects().stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        SampleObject::getNumber,
        Collector.of(
            SampleObjectAccumulator::new,
            SampleObjectAccumulator::accept,
            SampleObjectAccumulator::merge
        )
    ))
    .entrySet().stream()
    .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey())
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        Map.Entry::getKey,
        e -> e.getValue().toSampleObject(e.getKey()),
        (left, right) -> { throw new AssertionError("All keys are expected to be unique"); },
        LinkedHashMap::new
    ));
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for your help! I'm getting a NullPointerExeception within the accept method from the accumulator: Cannot invoke "java.lang.StringBuilder.append(String)" because "this.valueOne" is null

Comment: Thanks for fixing!
I want to concat valueOne and valueTwo. But if one of them is null only the other value should be visible. If both are null it should also return null.

Comment: @noob123 *"concat valueOne and valueTwo"* - this phrase is not very clear: you need to concatenate `valueOne` with `valueOne` from another object (same for `valueTwo`), correct? And what about the `valueThree`? If you don't want to concatenate `valueThree` which value from the aggregated objects should be preserved?

Comment: @noob123 Just in case, the code above concatenates all three values of the objects with the same `number` property: `valueOne` with `valueOne`, `valueTwo` with `valueTwo`,  `valueThree` with  `valueThree`. (sure, it can be changed if required)

Comment: Sorry, what I mean is that null values should be ignored. So when it iterates through all SampleObject with the same number it should just process values that are not null. If we look at the example from the question the accumulator would return for valueOne= "1nullnull" instead of "1" for valueTwo="null2null".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250751/discussion-between-alexander-ivanchenko-and-noob123).

Comment: alright I joined